# Database observer function not acting as observer in viewDidLoad, only viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that is in charge of observing the database. It sets some dictionaries upon first load, and then keeps an eye on changes thereafter and updates those dictionaries accordingly. When called in `viewDidAppear`, this works perfectly. But if I move it to `viewDidLoad`, it sets the values initially, but doesn't "observe" - in other words if I change one of the values, for example status, that change is not reflected until I leave the view and come back.

I need to have it in `viewDidLoad` for other reasons - why exactly is it only properly working as an observer if it's in `viewDidAppear`, and is there anything I can change to make it work as an observer in `viewDidLoad`?

This is the function:

```
func getParticipantInfo() {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomIdGlobal)
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            for each in snapDict {

                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let gender = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let name = each.value["name"] as! String
                let status = each.value["status"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.nameDictionary.setValue(name, forKey: uid)
                self.genderDictionary.setValue(gender, forKey: uid)
                self.handleDictionary.setValue(handle, forKey: uid)
                self.statusDictionary.setValue(status, forKey: uid)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Nav bar
                    self.navCollectionView?.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can see is that you are observing only `.childAdded` events. You'll have to subscribe to all the changes in order to trigger the event. try subscribing to `.value` event which will listen to all the changes on Database and reflect in app.

As far as `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` is concerned, make sure that you have setup all the class variables before attaching a subscriber to Firebase. `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` doesn't matter as far as the setup is right.